# GA Universal Analytics: Multiple Domains

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

Using the Universal GA tracking code, I'd like to be able to setup multiple domains for tracking, but only have the main "domain" actually stored/created in GA, as the other domains will be completely variable based on what is pointing to my application. So, based on what I understand from the docs, I have the following:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  @if ($custom_domain)
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', {
      'cookieDomain': '{{ $custom_domain }}'
    });
  @else
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
  @endif
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

What I'd like to know is if in the dashboard I'll be able to filter by these separate `cookieDomain` values so I can get accurate stats based on that domain only. Similarly, I have subdomains as well, which I'll want to make sure I can also poll in the dashboard, but I believe the `auto` param on the fallback `send` should take care of that. Thanks for any clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot filter by the cookie domain parameter. That merely determines, well, the cookie domain (i.e. if it's set wrong GA cannot set a cookie an will not track). "auto" already takes care of your use case (it means "set the cookie at the highest possible level of the domain".  The best use case is if you want to isolate tracking in a domain from it's subdomains, else "auto" will do fine).

The domain name is automatically captured in the "host name" data field and you can filter using that - you do not need to change the tracking code.

Comment: Hi @Eikie thanks for the response! So am I correct in assuming that I'd be using the `else`  option here and I should be able to filter by the hostname in the dashboard if I wanted to pull that out via an API?

Comment: Yes, that's it (the cookie domain option is more relevant to excluding (sub)domains than including them, auto will set it automatically to the highest possible level). And hostname reflects the tracked domain so you can filter by that. Remember that if pages on different domains have the same name their pageviews will be added up in the reports unless you add the hostname filter to break the results down by domain.

Comment: Thanks so much, great explanation!